# Python generating list using for loop, finding maxValue

Tags: python, list

The question is to write a function called `randNumMaxFor(n, maxValue)`, with a for loop that generates a list of `n` random numbers between `0` and `maxValue`.  I can get the random list generated with a for loop but I have no clue how to get to the next step.  Thanks for any hints or tips.

```
import random
def randomNumbers(n):    
    #create an empty list
    myList=[]

    #While loop to create new numbers
    for n in range(0,9):
        #create a random integer between 0 and 9, inclusive
        randomNumber=int(random.random()*10)

        #add the random number to the list of random numbers using the append() method
        myList.append(randomNumber)

    return myList
```

Comment: What's the 'next step'?

Comment: What happens to the `n` you pass in as a parameter? It's re-used in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> for loop that generates a list of n random numbers between 0 and maxValue

Your loop doesn't iterate from `0` to `n`. Replace with this:

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

You can use [randint()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint) to generate random numbers between `0` to `maxValue`. It will be something like `randint(0, maxValue)`.

You can then `sort` the list and return the last value which will be the `max` value

```
return sorted(myList)[len(myList) - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def randNumMaxFor(n, maxValue):
    ret = []
    for i in range(n):
        ret.append(random.random() * maxValue)
    return ret

>>> randNumMaxFor(5, 100)
[26.72290088458923,
 59.19115828283099,
 92.35251365446278,
 21.0800837007157,
 44.83968075845669]
```

Comment: you can use a list comprehension here: `return [random.random() * maxValue for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Yes, I just assumed it was a homework task and used more simple syntax.